# Sort questions by random

Tags: feature-request, sorting

For answering a question which nobody answered before, I just thought it would be nice to have questions sorted by random. Today, I sometimes go to the last page of the result list for [unanswered Java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?filter=need-answers). This is page 22712 and goes back to 2008. When taking the newest questions, I'm too slow to be the first person answering (which is not the end of the world, but might be disappointing if someone else's answer gets accepted). If I could pick one from the middle (=random), I would have both a chance for a recent question and enough time for writing a good and high-quality answer...

Comment: you can just pick a random page and go there `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?page=5123&sort=newest&pagesize=50`

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry, your link didn't work for me, I'm always landing on page 1 and the url gets rewritten to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you on the new nav?

Comment: @Daniel, you could hit the page 2 button to get a working url for you then change the number

Comment: @NickA No. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?page=2, when clickling I go to page 2 (but the url in the address bar is still without params). When pasting the url directly it goes to page 1. New nav? likely, but not sure

Comment: Have you seen the list of new questions? They are pretty random already.  You've got the no actual question asked, mixed with the give me the code, mixed with the debug my code, mixed with the absolute gibberish, etc.  All in all its pretty random.

Comment: It doesn't feel random. The oldest question here (pos 15) is ~ '30 mins ago'. I'm looking more for '2 months ago', '16 weeks ago', '1 year ago'

Answer (score 4):

There is a [no-answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions#page=1&pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=java&filter=!9YdnSPuG8&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint in the StackAPI that gives you questions that have no answers yet (don't confuse with unanswered).

With a bit of Stack Snippet Fu and JavaScript you can happily click the button that will give you a link to a random question out of the collection of unanswered questions.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // build api url for an endpoint and its optional parameters
    function apiBuilder(endpoint, params) {
        var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
            urlPath = url + endpoint;
        // params.key ='bring your own';
        if (params !== undefined)  {
            var query = [];
            for(var prop in params) {
                if (params.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    query.push( prop + '=' + encodeURI(params[prop]));
                }
            }
            urlPath = urlPath + '?' + query.join('&');
        }
        return urlPath;
    }

    // build url for /Question endpoint
    function apiQuestionBuilder(site, tag, page) {
        return apiBuilder(
            'questions/no-answers', 
            {
                site: site,
                tagged: tag,
                order: 'asc',
                page: page || 1,
                pagesize: 1,
                sort: 'activity',
                filter: '!9YdnSPuG8'
            });
    }

    // do a get on the API for the given url
    // and invoke the callback with the JSON result
    function API () {

        var backlog = [],
            getfunction;

        // simply push the params on the queue
        function cacheget(url, callback) {
            backlog.push({ url: url, callback: callback});
        }

        // this makes the actual xhr call
        function realget(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // handles pending calls by invoking realget
            // and resetting the getfunction when 
            // the backlog is cleared
            function handleBacklog() {
                var item = backlog.shift();
                if (item !== undefined) {
                    console.log('from cache');
                    // handle this single item
                    realget(item.url, item.callback);
                } 
                if (backlog.length === 0) {
                    // if the backlog is empty 
                    // use realget for the next call
                    getfunction = realget;
                }
            }

            xhr.addEventListener('error', function () {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            });

            xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var backoff = response.backoff || 0;
                // backoff received
                if (backoff > 0) {
                    // start caching calls
                    console.log('backoff recv');
                    getfunction = cacheget;
                }
                if (response.error_id === 502) {
                    console.log(reponse.error_message);
                    getfunction = cacheget;
                    backoff = 120;
                }
                // process pending backlog
                setTimeout(handleBacklog, backoff * 1000);
                // invoke the callback
                callback(response);
            });
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();
        }

        // calls either xhr or the cache
        function get(url, callback)
        {
            getfunction(url, callback);
        }

        // initially we start with a realget
        getfunction = realget;

        // return the public api
        return {
            get: get
        };
    }

    var SEApi = new API(); // keep an instance
    
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
    
    function createResult(q) {
       // just add the link
       var a = document.createElement('a'),
           res = document.getElementById('result');
           
       a.innerHTML = q.title;
       var cd = new Date(q.creation_date*1000);
       a.title = cd.getFullYear() 
               + '-' 
               + cd.getMonth() 
               + '-'
               + cd.getDay()
               + ' | score: ' 
               + q.score 
               + ' | views: ' 
               + q.view_count
       a.href = q.link;
       res.appendChild(a);
    }
    
    function getRandom(tag, max) {
      // get a random one-page no-answers result
      SEApi.get(apiQuestionBuilder('stackoverflow',tag, getRandomInt(1, max)), function (data) {
          if (data.items && data.items.length > 0) {
             // make sure we see something
             createResult(data.items[0]);
          } else {
             var err = document.getElementById('error');
             err.style.display= 'block';
             err.textContent = 'no question?'
          }
        });
    }
    
    // get the tag entered and fetch something
    function fetchOne(total) {
      var tag = document.getElementById('tag').value;
      getRandom(tag, total);
    }
    
    // start it all off
    function go() {
      var err = document.getElementById('error'),
          btn = document.getElementById('go');
      err.style.display='none';
      // call the /questions/no-answers for the total count
      SEApi.get(
        apiQuestionBuilder(
          'stackoverflow',
          document.getElementById('tag').value), 
        function (data) {
          if (data.items && data.items.length > 0) {
            // if we have that, get a random one
            // let's re-wire the initial handler to reduce calls
            btn.removeEventListener('click', go);
            btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
              fetchOne(data.total);
            });
            fetchOne(data.total);
          } else {
            err.style.display= 'block';
            err.textContent = 'no data received'
          }
        });
    }
    
    document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', go);
      
})();
```

```css
#error {display:none; }
#result a {display:block}
```

```html
<div id ="error">
</div>
<div> 
<label for="tag">enter a tag:</label>
<input type="text" id='tag' />
<button id="go">Pick a random question!</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

What I'm basically doing is first determine how many questions there are in total. That is a value that is returned in the first call to `/no-answers`. The subsequent calls fetch a page between 1 and the total of questions. By requesting a pagesize of 1 the solution is simple enough to have your browser generate a random number and use that as the page to fetch. Once the question object is retrieved it is added to the DOM as a link. The tooltip of the link shows the creation-date, score and view count.

Comment: Nice job @rene :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a site called [Dice Stack](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/) to get a list of random questions, and you can set some filters too (e.g. site, minimum score, tags, answer status).

For more information, visit its post on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1643/dice-stack-find-a-random-question).

However, *it **does not** have filter for date range*, so you might often get very old questions.